# Как создать inline кнопку инициирующую нажатие команды в телеграм боте?

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Написал небольшой код по многоуровневому списку. Сделал кнопку назад(в приведенном коде ее нет, взял немного старую версию кода потому что под рукой она), чтобы кидала на уровень назад(кроме как на первый, т.к. кнопка назад привязана к значениям предыдущих кнопок, а начальная менюшка вызывается командой старт). Так вот, как сделать кнопку "В начало", чтобы она меняла содержимое текущего сообщения на первоначальное состояние(после нажатия кнопки start)?

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    l1_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1', callback_data='level1_1')
    l1_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('2', callback_data='level1_2')
    l1_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('3', callback_data='level1_3')
    l1_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('4', callback_data='level1_4')
    l1_5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('5', callback_data='level1_5')
    l1_6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('6', callback_data='level1_6')
    markup.add(l1_1, l1_2, l1_3, l1_4, l1_5, l1_6)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Чем я могу вам помочь? \n '
                                      '1. Узнать о ….\n '
                                      '2. Получить …. \n '
                                      '3. Ответы на часто задаваемые вопросы. \n '
                                      '4. Вызвать оператора. \n '
                                      '5. О нашем ….. \n '
                                      '6. Оставить отзыв.', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback_data(callback):
    if callback.data == 'level1_1':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
            l2_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='1', callback_data='level2_1')
            l2_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='2', callback_data='level2_2')
            l2_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='3', callback_data='level2_3')
            l2_4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='4', callback_data='level2_4')
            l2_5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='5', callback_data='level2_5')
            l2_6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='6', callback_data='level2_6')
            l2_7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='7', callback_data='level2_7')
            l2_8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='8', callback_data='level2_8')
            l2_9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='9', callback_data='level2_9')
            l2_10 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='10', callback_data='level2_10')
            markup.add(l2_1, l2_2, l2_3, l2_4, l2_5, l2_6, l2_7, l2_8, l2_9, l2_10)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id,
                                  text='1. <b>Категории ….</b>, имеющие право ….. \n'
                                       '2. <b>Перечень ….</b>, необходимых для …...\n'
                                       '3. <b>Срок</b> предоставления …. \n'
                                       '4. <b>Основания для ….</b> \n'
                                       '5. <b>Основания для ….</b> \n'
                                       '6. <b>Возобновление</b> …\n'
                                       '7. Максимальное <b>время …</b> \n'
                                       '8. <b>Срок …</b> ... \n'
                                       '9. <b>Стоимость</b> ... \n'
                                       '10.Начисление …<b>Способы</b> ', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback_data(callback):
    if callback.data == 'level2_1':
            markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
            l3_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='level1_1')
            l3_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='В начало', callback_data='Start_2')

            markup.add(l3_1, l3_2)
            bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id,
                                  text='<b>Категории</b>, \n'
                                       '1. <b>ррррр:</b>\n'
                                       '        рррр; \n'
                                       '        ррррр; \n'
                                       '        рррр; \n'
                                       '        рррр. \n'
                                       '2. <b>рррррр.</b> \n'
                                       '3. <b>ррррр </b> \n'
                                       '4. <b>рррр </b> \n', parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант можно вынести то что делается на старте в отдельную функцию и в зависимости от того, откуда она вызывается, либо отправлять сообщение, либо редактировать:

```python
import telebot
from telebot import types
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

def start_message(message, edit=False):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=3)
    markup.add(*(types.InlineKeyboardButton(str(i), callback_data='level1_'+str(i)) for i in range(1,7)))
    if edit:
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=message.chat.id, message_id=message.id,
                              text=messages[0], parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, messages[0], parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    start_message(message)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: callback.data)
def check_callback_data(callback):
    if callback.data == 'level1_1':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
        markup.add(*(types.InlineKeyboardButton(str(i), callback_data='level2_'+str(i)) for i in range(1,11)))
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id,
                              text=messages[1], parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)
    if callback.data == 'level2_1':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=5)
        markup.add(
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Назад', callback_data='level1_1'),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='В начало', callback_data='start')
        )
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=callback.message.chat.id, message_id=callback.message.id,
                              text=messages[2], parse_mode='HTML', reply_markup=markup)
    if callback.data == 'start':
        start_message(callback.message, True)
```

Я тут текст сообщений убрал в переменную `messages` ну и немного сократил код генераторами.

Ещё у тебя ошибка, что ты несколько раз объявляешь `callback_query_handler`, т.е. далее одного уровня программа не выполнится, тоже поправил.

Comment: просидел кучу времени не понимая почему третий уровень кнопок не работает. Постараюсь разобраться сейчас. Есть тут возможность написать в лс/на почту? Есть вопрос по коду, объяснил бы если не против. не бесплатно